# malloc() on double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

```
double *p;
p = malloc(sizeof(p));
if (p != NULL)
{
    *p = 5.15;
}
```

For some reason, `p = malloc(sizeof(p));`doesn't work. I try to allocate as much memory as `p` needs. What is wrong with that?

Comment: You want to allocate as much memory as required by what `p` points to. So `malloc(sizeof(*p));`

Comment: "I try to allocate as much memory as `p` needs. " Why on earth do you want to do such a thing? `p` will be expected to be pointing data having type `double` so the size of buffer should be `sizeof(double)` or `sizeof(*p)`.

Comment: Actually `p = malloc(sizeof(p));` works, it allocates the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I try to allocate as much memory as `p` needs.*

`p` itself (as a variable) has got the (own) memory allocated, what you're trying is basically allocate the memory for which `p` will be pointing to.

Here, `p` points to a `double`, so it needs to have a memory area to be able to store a `double` value. So, the allocation should be equal to the size of a `double`, i.e,

```
p = malloc(sizeof*p);
```